# Can I set a description value in a UISwitch?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswitch

I have 40 UISwitches on my View in a TableView. I give the switch a #selector objc function. The objc function can only take the sender (the UISwitch) as a parameter. Is there a way I can describe which switch is calling the objc function? The field UISwitch.description is immutable.

Comment: The sender is the switch. What do you need other than that? It's unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `cellForRowAt` do

```
cell.switch.tag = indexPath.row
```

---

```
@objc func switchChanged(_ sender:UISwitch) { 
   print(arr[sender.tag]) // model item of the changed switch
}
```